# Showing when an operator $T$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, normed-spaces

If $T$ is a linear transformation on $\mathbb{R^n}$ with $\|T-S\|< 1$, and $S$ is the invertible, how can I show $T$ invertible?

I need help for this problem. I think the inverse of $T$ is $S^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(I-TS^{-1})^k$. Since for the similar problem when $S=I$, the $T^{-1}$ would be $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(I-T)^k$. I wanted to make similar argument but $S$ can be any invertible operator not just a multiple of $I$.

Comment: What if $T=0$ and $S=\frac{1}{2}I$? I think you should require at least that $\left\|T-S\right\|<\left\|S\right\|$...

Comment: Or, if you don't want to consider scalar multiples of the identity, consider $T=0$, $S'$ any invertible operator, and $S=\frac{1}{2\|S'\|}S'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is stated in the comments, $\|T-S\|<1$ is not strong enough to ensure $T$ is invertible. A sufficient condition is that $\|T-S\|<\|S^{-1}\|^{-1}$, because then
$$\|S^{-1}T-I\|\leq\|S^{-1}\|\|T-S\|<1,$$
and you can apply what you mentioned to show that $S^{-1}T$ is invertible, and therefore $T$ is invertible.